# How to left alignment of formulas in parentheses?

Tags: equations, alignment

I want  the follow one, but my code dosen't achieve, can someone help?
[image]

my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\rho=\left\{
             \begin{array}{lr}
             0, & |v_{y}^{CH}|<V_{1}^{T} \\
             y=0.5, & V_{1}^{T}\leq |v_{y}^{CH}|\leq V_{2}^{T}, \\
             z=1, & |v_{y}^{CH}|> V_{2}^{T}             
             \end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

the result of my code:
[image]

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the `cases` environment provided by the `amsmath` package (see the end of section 3.7 of its manual), as well as at the variants thereof added by the `mathtools` package (see section 3.4.3 of its manual).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the table with `ll` and not `lr`

```
\begin{array}{ll}
```

[image: array]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\rho=\left\{
             \begin{array}{ll}
             0, & |v_{y}^{CH}|<V_{1}^{T} \\
             y=0.5, & V_{1}^{T}\leq |v_{y}^{CH}|\leq V_{2}^{T}, \\
             z=1, & |v_{y}^{CH}|> V_{2}^{T}             
             \end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh``thank for your help, I think I just asked a stupid question...but thanks again!!

Comment: @berlinpand That's what I like about LaTeX: even after several years of practice, I'm still a beginner!

Answer (score 9):

Why not use a simple `cases` environment?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\rho=
             \begin{cases}
             0, & |v_{y}^{CH}|<V_{1}^{T} \\[1ex]
             y=0.5, & V_{1}^{T}\leq |v_{y}^{CH}|\leq V_{2}^{T}, \\[1ex]
             z=1, & |v_{y}^{CH}|> V_{2}^{T}
             \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one looks much better